# What triggers Expired Password Visualforce Page?

Tags: reset-password

Exactly as title says - I am curious what triggers the expired password page to be sent to a user?

Obviously it is the expired password that triggers it - but I am curious what field (on the User record) the trigger is looking to? And is there a flow  /pb/trigger that looks at this field and sends an email/redirects user to the page that asks them to reset their password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Reports and build a report on the User object, you can select a field called `Password Expiration Date` which will show when the user's password will expire.

For some weird reason, this field is not available via Apex. You can query another field called `LastPasswordChangeDate` which doesn't really tell you when the user's password will expire, but depending upon your use case gives you an option to perform some calculations.

So to answer your question, when the user tries to login, the system checks the `Password Expiration Date` on the user object and if it is in the past, then redirects the user to password reset page.